# Where does Spring Security get its default http configuration from?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 3.2.4 and trying to determine where it gets its default configuration from.  For example, when using the following configuration:

```
<http use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/denied" access="permitAll" />
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" session-authentication-error-url="/login.jsp?authFailed=true"> 
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="10" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/login.html" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>
    </session-management>

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login login-page="/secure/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/secure/denied" />
    <logout logout-url="/secure/logout" logout-success-url="/" />
    <expression-handler ref="defaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
</http>
```

Something in a Spring configuration somewhere, is telling Spring to instantiate the `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` and set the login-page to "/secure/login", etc.  I realize that it is the `form-login` tag that is doing this magic for me, but where within Spring is the `form-login` tag translated to mean the LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint, etc?

Similarly, by default, Spring will instantiate a filter chain of name `org.springframework.security.filterChains`, but can't find where that bean is defined.  I presume it is in an xml configuration file within one of the Spring Security jars, but I can't find it anywhere.

Where are all these defaults configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [SecurityNamespaceHandler](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config/3.1.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/config/SecurityNamespaceHandler.java/) and work your way down from there. As you can see, it is in the spring-security-config artifact, in package `org.springframework.security.config`.

Comment: Thanks.  I found it in the `spring-security-config` artifact.  In META-INF/spring.handlers, there is the defn for the SecurityNamespaceHandler.  Then, I was able to find the different config classes in `org.springframework.security.config` as you indicated.  Ex: `org.springframework.security.config.http.FormLoginBeanDefinitionParser.class`